# Read MIPS CPU register using asm instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I'd like to print the `$ra` (return address) register in my assert function for debugging purpose. I'm working on MIPS CPU.
I tried the following code but the compiler doesn't like it:

```
unsigned int  RA;
unsigned int* pRA = &RA;
asm volatile("sw $ra, %0" : "=r" (pRA));
```

or

```
static volatile unsigned int RA;
asm ("mov $ra, %0" : "=m"(RA));
```

I've found a GCC documentation regarding inline/extended assembly but it seems unclear to me.

Answer (score 4):

Either of the following should work:

```
 unsigned int x;
 asm volatile ("move %0, $ra" : "=r" (x));
 asm volatile ("sw $ra, %0" : "=m" (x));
```

If you insist on using a pointer value `asm volatile ("sw $ra, %0" : "=m" (*pRA));` is the way to go (without the dereferencing you'll get a `pRA` will end up pointer to the the return address rather having the value stored in `RA`). You can read more about the constraints in the [GCC inline assembly HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s6).

Comment: It might be worth linking to the [official gcc docs on inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html).  This menu contains the links for constraints as well as the details for gcc's extended asm support.  I know the OP said he had "found a GCC Documentation," but it's unclear exactly what he found or where he found it.